# Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Videos' not found

Tags: admin, error, ce-1.9.1.0

I'm getting this error message when I open a product from admin -

> Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Videos' not found in /home/firstgea/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Abstract.php on line 146

***History:***  I used a 1.8 database and a clean install of Magento 1.9.1. So I think it's a video plugin but I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Go to System > Configuration and select the Advance tab (which his under 'ADVANCE' section.) Then try to disable the relevant extension

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my problem.  What a huge feeling of accomplishment.  I used two different answers from various others and was able to get rid of the attribute.

1. Backed up my system.
2. Went to database and located “eav_attribute” table.
3. Looked up Videos and changed the value of is_user_defined to 1
4. Logged back in to Admin and located the attribute Videos
5. Delete
6. More errors and nearly paniced, but was comfortable since I did a back-up.
7. Found solution for my errors here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480310/magento-exception-printing-is-disabled-by-default-for-security-reasons

And that was it!  Everything works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Finn this case, you need to `create class` for your `custom input field`  `Videos` at magento library folder location **lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element**
Here you find list of input files `relative class`.

For case of view,you need to create the

```
<?php
class Varien_Data_Form_Element_Video extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract {
    public function __construct($data) {
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->setType('file');
    }

    public function getElementHtml() {
        $html = '';
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $url = $this->_getUrl();
            if( !preg_match("/^http\:\/\/|https\:\/\//", $url) ) {
                $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $url;
            }
            $html = '<a href="'.$url.'" onclick="VideoPreview(\''.$this->getHtmlId().'_video\'); return false;"><img src="'.$url.'" id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'_video" title="'.$this->getValue().'" alt="'.$this->getValue().'" height="22" width="22" /></a> ';
        }
        $this->setClass('input-file');
        $html.= parent::getElementHtml();
        $html.= $this->_getDeleteCheckbox();
        return $html;
    }

    protected function _getDeleteCheckbox() {
        $html = '';
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $label = Mage::helper('core')->__('Delete video');
            $html .= '<span>';
            $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="'.parent::getName().'[delete]" value="1" id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'_delete"'.($this->getDisabled() ? ' disabled="disabled"': '').'/>';
            $html .= '<label for="'.$this->getHtmlId().'_delete"'.($this->getDisabled() ? '' : '').'> '.$label.'</label>';
            $html .= $this->_getHiddenInput();
            $html .= '</span>';
        }
        return $html;
    }

    protected function _getHiddenInput() {
        return '<input type="hidden" name="'.parent::getName().'[value]" value="'.$this->getValue().'" accept="video/*" />';
    }

    protected function _getUrl() {
        return $this->getValue();
    }

    public function getName() {
        return  $this->getData('name');
    }
}
```

Comment: I ADDED the above code to text, Amit, and I got this error -          Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/firstgea/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Text.php on line 54

Comment: Ignore above.  I had included <?php and didn't need it.  But I am not sure if I was suppose to add it to an element or create a new element.  So I tried with text.php and also with Abstract.php and I got the same error message